# understand taxes when geting money from a project built long time ago plus my full time job

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, bank-account

I have been employed full time in the UK for 1 year, I have no other side jobs and the company I am working for is paying taxes and national insurance for my salary, transferring the net salary to my bank account.
I previously worked on a project before coming to UK; this project has started to get some traffic and income, but I am not working on it now. I need to get this money to my UK bank account, but at the same time I want to let the Gov know about this money, so as to get it taxed.
I am new here to UK, so what are the first steps I should take or who I should contact to get this sorted?

Comment: Could you please clarify: is this money already yours / in your own account, but just located outside the UK? If so, when did you earn it (roughly - i.e. what was the invoice date or similar) and did you pay tax on it in whatever jurisdiction it is in at the time you received it originally? And what jurisdiction is that?

Comment: @Vicky the money still with clients outside UK and they will start to send, so I don't have it yet, but I need to get ready, and these money are not taxed outside UK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register as self-employed with HMRC (it is perfectly fine to be self-employed and employed by an employer at the same time, in exactly your kind of situation). Then, when the income arrives you will need to declare it on your yearly tax return.

HMRC information about registering for self-employment and declaring the income is here: https://www.gov.uk/working-for-yourself/overview

There's a few extra hoops if your clients are outside the UK; the detail depends on whether they are in the EU or not. More details about this are here: https://www.gov.uk/online-and-distance-selling-for-businesses/selling-overseas .

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, but I have a concern, In fact I am not self employed and not working  an another job, so can't I just submit the amount of coming money, something like a Self Assessment tax return https://www.gov.uk/self-assessment-tax-returns/who-must-send-a-tax-return

Comment: If you have income from work you have done, that is not income from employment (where you were employed by someone else), then it counts as self-employment. That tax return is exactly what you will have to do, but the pages you will have to fill in on it are the self employment ones.